# e.preventDefault() still sends me to another page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, visual-studio-code

In this exercise I am supposed to make a grocery list by submiting a form, but when i press submit it sends me to another page even if I use e.preventDefault()

```
const container = document.querySelector('#list');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const getProduct = form.elements.product.value;
    const getQty = form.elements.qty.value;
     
    const newli = document.createElement('li');
    newli.append(getQty);
    newli.append(` ${getProduct}`);
    container.append(newli);
    
    form.elements.product.value = '';
    form.elements.qty.value = '';
})
```

This is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
 <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form action="/nowhere">
        <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
        <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how exactly is your `form` variable declared? this information missing in your code example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking your time to solve my problem, i managed to fix it, the actual problem was the position of <script src="app.js"></script>, i was used to type it to in the <head> because of css, but it has to be in <body>, also i kept /nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just modify `action="/nowhere"` to `action=""` this is the error.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#list');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const getProduct = form.elements.product.value;
    const getQty = form.elements.qty.value;
     
    const newli = document.createElement('li');
    newli.append(getQty);
    newli.append(` ${getProduct}`);
    container.append(newli);
    
    form.elements.product.value = '';
    form.elements.qty.value = '';
})
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
 <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form action="">
        <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
        <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking your time to solve my problem, i managed to fix it, the actual problem was the position of <script src="app.js"></script>, i was used to type it to in the <head> because of css, but it has to be in <body>, also i kept /nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed giving an id to your form `const form = document.querySelector('#form1');` remove the action

```
<form id="form1" action="">
```

try out this and run the code snippet

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#list');
const form = document.querySelector('#form1');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const getProduct = form.elements.product.value;
    const getQty = form.elements.qty.value;
     
    const newli = document.createElement('li');
    newli.append(getQty);
    newli.append(` ${getProduct}`);
    container.append(newli);
    
    form.elements.product.value = '';
    form.elements.qty.value = '';
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
 <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form id="form1" action="">
        <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
        <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking your time to solve my problem, i managed to fix it, the actual problem was the position of <script src="app.js"></script>, i was used to type it to in the <head> because of CSS, but it has to be in <body>, also I kept /nowhere.